# How to show the cursor coordinate in selection and dropper in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs4

I am using Adobe Photoshop CS4 to edit a picture.

The problems I have are that I don't know where I can see the mouse cursor coordinate while I move my mouse.

- **Example 1.** In Paint.NET, whenever I move mouse cursor, I can immediately see the feedback from bottom-right corner (x, y), how can I see such info in Photoshop while I use eyedropper function?
- **Example 2.** When in crop mode, I drag-drop a rectangle but I cannot see the size of the created region of interest?

Answer (score 12):

Window --> Information... a palette appears, and you can see the coordinates of the cursor.